# Using Flyway with SQLite database in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, sqlite, flyway

In my Spring Boot project, I need to use SQLite database. I have setup the SQLite database successfully like below:

The dependencies:

```
implementation("org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.42.0.0")
implementation("org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-community-dialects")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:sqlite:file:myDb.db?cache=shared
    username: root
    password: root
```

As you can see above, I am using **on disk** SQLite database, the database file is `myDb.db`.

I also created the datasource bean:

```
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(props.getDriverClassName());
        dataSource.setUrl(props.getUrl());
        dataSource.setUsername(props.getUsername());
        dataSource.setPassword(props.getPassword());
        return dataSource;
    }
```

I verified this SQLite database setup works, because when I start running my project the entity classes' associated db tables are created successfully in database.

**Next, I try to setup Flyway as below:**

I included dependency:

```
implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core:8.5.11")
```

In `application.yml`, I added:

```
spring:
  ...
  flyway:
    baseline-on-migrate: true
    schemas: myDb
    enabled: true
    url: jdbc:sqlite:file:myDb.db?cache=shared
    user: root
    password: root
    validate-on-migrate: true
    locations: "classpath:db/migration"
```

I also created directory  `/db/migration` directory under `src/main/resources/`

But when start running the project, **I end up with error:**

```
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: Unable to check whether table "myDb"."flyway_schema_history" exists`
```

I do understand in SQLite there is no concept of "database schema", so I also tried manually create the table `flyway_schema_history` after which then start running the project, but I still get the same error.

How can I make Flyway + SQLite work in spring boot? What am I missing?

(I doubt it is a database connection issue since before I setup Flyway the project can successfully make a connection & create tables based on JPA Entities. Or Could it be I miss some SQLite specific configurations of Flyway to establish DB connection for Flyway??? I'm not sure...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving too much parameter, below is my application yaml file

```yaml
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: create-drop
    hibernate.show_sql: true
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:sqlite:file:myDb.db?cache=shared
    username: root
    password: root
  h2:
    console.enabled: true
  flyway:
    baseline-on-migrate: true
#    schemas: myDb
    enabled: true
    url: jdbc:sqlite:file:myDb.db?cache=shared
    user: root
    password: root
    validate-on-migrate: true
    locations: "classpath:db/migration"
```

basically I just commented schema and things started working. I also added h2 console and start checking mydb and this is how it looks
[image: h2 console with sqlie]
below are the parameters for h2 console login
[image: h2 console login for sqlite]
[here](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/spring-examples/tree/master/flyway-sqlite) you can find the full working example.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite, there's no separation of schemas like in some other databases. So, in your Flyway configuration, you shouldn't specify a separate schema.

```
spring:
  ...
  flyway:
    baseline-on-migrate: true
    enabled: true
    url: jdbc:sqlite:file:myDb.db?cache=shared
    user: root
    password: root
    validate-on-migrate: true
    locations: "classpath:db/migration"
```